# Error al iniciar MySQL con XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

me podrían ayudar a resolver este problema que me esta pasando al intentar conectarme con MySQL desde Xampp, al encenderlo carga y al momento se desconecta y me manda este error en mysql_error.log, ya revise los puertos y están correctos, lo estuve utilizando correctamente pero ya hoy no me dejo acceder.

Agradezco por sus comentarios.

2020-06-10 10:51:13 3558 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2020-06-10 10:51:13 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2020-06-10 10:51:14 13656 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.

2020-06-10 10:51:14 13656 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start

2020-06-10 10:51:14 13656 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1267474912

2020-06-10 10:51:15 9632 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started

2020-06-10 10:51:15 13656 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2020-06-10 10:51:15 13656 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Comment: Quizás tienes otro programa corriendo el mismo puerto, no has instalado o ejecutado algún programa actualmente?

Comment: Hola @Joe solamente ocupo workbench y sublime, no he corrido ningún otro programa por el momento.

Comment: Cuál versión de MySql tienes instalada?

Comment: Hola @Joe la versión de MySql es 5.0.12 y trabajo con PHP 7.3.14

Answer (score 0):

Es por la versión, elimina estos archivos  `ibdata1 file , ib_logfile1, ib_logfile1` que se encuentran en `c:xampp\mysql\data directory` y reinicia el servidor. o setear el valor de `innodb_use_sys_malloc = 1` en uno, como está en el ejemplo. Cualquier de las dos.

Comment: Hola @Joe Ya intente ambos, también le cambie de puerto y el problema sigue persistiendo.